# How to pull SQL query into trigger?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, triggers

I am using oracle database.

I am trying to write a trigger on tables. I didn't mention any primary key, foreign key constraints on those tables. I am trying to achieve those using triggers.

I wrote triggers for primary key and foreign key constraints.

If I want to delete some foreign key record in the table, if I mention cascade then it will delete the record. IF I don't mention the cascade in the SQL query while deleting the record it should display an error.. saying that it is a primary key for the other table so, you can't delete.

For this, I need to check the String 'CASCADE' is present in the SQL query inside my trigger.
So, how can I pull the delete query on some X table into my trigger.

Comment: Why not just create Primary keys and Foreign keys ??? you can save yourself a lot of hardwork :)

Comment: A suggestion - please remove the SQL Server tag if your question is related to Oracle. Thanks!

Comment: I started learning PL/SQL.. so, I just want to try in different ways. That's it. I just googled it.. but I didn't find any answer. I just want to know.. is it possible or not? If it is possible then how to do it. Sorry.. if my question is not clear or wrong.

Comment: If this is just a learning execise, good.  But implementing integrity constraints such as PK, FK with triggers is just a terrible idea any which way you look at it.  Assuming you still want to do this, your question then, is not clear at all.  Please show concrete details - tables, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the trigger, you can't get the information whether `CASCADE` was specified in the delete statement or not.

Also, implementing primary key constraints and foreign key constraints in your triggers is a terrible idea. Try some other excercise instead. While you may think your solution will work, it probably won't in multi-user, multi-session environment. Example:

1. Session A might insert some record and check for the FK constraint. It passes your validation.
2. Session B deletes the record to which the FK constraint is pointing.
3. Session A commits.
4. Session B commits, leaving your record with a missing FK.

The way Oracle handles this is by locking entries in the index/table. You don't want to go there.